# iOS : Simulate errors on Game Center Sandbox report

Tags: iphone, ios, sandbox, leaderboard

i'm about to finish my update on a game called WarpOut (available on App Store, check it out); this update includes Game Center functionalities.

I'm reporting high scores as well as achievements.

For now, it works on a Game Center Sandbox (as it is supposed to), and i've implemented code to postpone report whenever an error occurs while reporting.

My question is this : since the sandbox is local, how can i simulate an error to check if the postpone report works properly ?

Comment: What do you mean the sandbox is local?  The sand box's scores are stored on a separate version of the Game Center server.  As for simulating an error, maybe try to send a score when you know you cannot, such as when the user does not have internet connection?

Comment: this is exactly what i meant when i said it's local (for which i was probably wrong). What i did is, i launched my app on my computer iphone simulator and shut down the internet connection...didn't get anything done (and my error handler started with a simple LOG). If you're sure that, with internet down, i should've got an error, maybe i should check this, but i use the sample code provided by Apple to report the score, so i guess the error handling is correct.

Comment: to be complete, i've shut down the internet connection once i've been logged in on Game Center with my sandbox account.